# bash script to Remove double quote from middle and add it at the end of the line

Tags: sed

I have file with below line.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -/opt/linux/agent.jar -max=5000" http.proxyHost=172.0.0.128
```

Im using below command to append proxyHost and it's value to end of the line using below command working fine, but I would like remove double quote from the middle and add it end the end, please help me.

```sh
sed -i '' -e '/^#/!s/agent\.jar.*/& http.proxyHost='"$PROXYHOST"'/' $_FILE
```

output should be like below:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -/opt/linux/agent.jar -max=5000 http.proxyHost=172.0.0.128"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sed 's/"$/ http.proxyHost=172.0.0.128"/' <<< 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -/opt/linux/agent.jar -max=5000"'
```

Substitute the double quote at the end of the line with the additional proxyhost data plus an ending double quote.

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` one-liner will move the last `"` character to the end of the line, for each line in the file.

```
sed 's/"\([^"]*\)$/\1"/' file
```

If you want to edit only the lines that begin with `JAVA_OPTS="`, then use

```
sed '/^JAVA_OPTS="/s/"\([^"]*\)$/\1"/' file
```

Or, if you want to append properly the `$PROXYHOST` to the line beginning with `JAVA_OPTS=` in the original file:

```
sed '/^JAVA_OPTS="/s/"$/'" $PROXYHOST"'"/' file
```

If the content of the variable `PROXYHOST` contains characters that are special to `sed` (such as `/` and `&`), they must be escaped by prepending a `\`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```sh
sed -E 's/(.*)"/\1/; s/$/"/'
```

The first part removes the *last* quote because `.*` is greedy.
Then add a double quote at the end of the line.

Or `perl -pe 's/.*\K"//; s/$/"/'` which works the same way